# How to display post from spesific custom post type's category on Elementor free?

Tags: wordpress, elementor, theming

I am trying to make an Elementor module for Custom Post Type, separate into 2 files.

[File 1] for setting control.

[File 2] to display the custom post type on the front page.

When I insert the Category directly to (File 2), everything works fine. The custom post type is displayed correctly. Can display post by category etc correctly.

But when I am trying to handle the category from the setting (File 2) it did not work. The post doesn't display.

How to collect the custom post type's category in Elementor?
Note: my custom post type name: event, taxonomy: catevent, and the category sample: test.

Here is my code:

Code in admin setting

```php
    protected function register_controls() {

        $terms = get_terms( array(
            'taxonomy' =>'catevent',
            'hide_empty' => true,
        ) );
    
        $cat_names = array();
        $cat_names = array('all');      
        foreach( $terms as $t ):
            $cat_names[$t->term_id] = $t->name;
        endforeach;
        

        $this->add_control(
                'cat_name',
                    [
                        'label'       => __( 'From Category', 'module-for-elementor' ),
                        'type' => Controls_Manager::SELECT2  ,
                        'multiple' => true,
                        'default' => 'uncategorized',
                        'options' => $cat_names,
                    ]
                    );
```

Code in the Loop

```php
      <?php $blog = array(
       'catevent' => $settings['cat_name'],
       'post_type'         => 'event',
       'post_status'       => 'publish',
       'posts_per_page'    => 1,
       'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
       'tax_query' => array( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )),
        );
      ?>
      <div class="module1ol">
      <?php $count = 0;
      $the_query = new WP_Query( $blog );
      if($the_query->have_posts()):
      while($the_query->have_posts()): 
      $the_query->the_post();   
    ?>
      <div class="module1-post">
        <div class="cat-color">
          <a class="entry-title" href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
            <?php esc_html_e(wp_trim_words( get_the_title(),8, ''), 'module-for-elementor'); ?>
            </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php  endwhile; ?>
      <?php  wp_reset_query(); 
            endif;?>
    </div>
```

Everything works fine when I insert the category directly like this but did not work when using code from (File 1).

```php
    <?php $blog = array(
       'catevent' => 'test',
       'post_type'         => 'event',
       'post_status'       => 'publish',
       'posts_per_page'    => 1,
       'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
       'tax_query' => array( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )),
        );
      ?>
```

Really appreciate any help anyone can provide.